# Drag TextView on Button - App crashes

Tags: android, view, drag-and-drop, widget

I am pretty new to Android programming and now I want to learn more about Drag and Drop actions. So my goal is to drag a TextView onto a custom Button and when I drop it the Text of the TextView should replace the Text of the Button.
For this I created a "DropTargetView" which extends Button:

```
public class DropTargetView extends Button implements View.OnDragListener{

private boolean mDropped;                                  
public CharSequence name;

public DropTargetView(Context context) {                   
    super(context);
    init();
}

public DropTargetView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public DropTargetView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    setOnDragListener(this);                                            
}
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    PropertyValuesHolder pvhX, pvhY;                                    

    switch (event.getAction()){
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:                             
            pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 0.5f);
            pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 0.5f);
            ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(this,pvhX,pvhY).start();
            mDropped = false;
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:                               
            pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1f);
            pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1f);
            ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(this,pvhX,pvhY).start();
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 0.75f);
            pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 0.75f);
            ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(this,pvhX,pvhY).start();
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX",0.5f);
            pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 0.5f);
            ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(this,pvhX,pvhY).start();
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:                                     
            Keyframe frame0 = Keyframe.ofFloat(0f, 0.75f);
            Keyframe frame1 = Keyframe.ofFloat(0.5f, 0f);
            Keyframe frame2 = Keyframe.ofFloat(1f, 0.75f);
            pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofKeyframe("scaleX", frame0, frame1, frame2);
            pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofKeyframe("scaleY", frame0, frame1, frame2);
            ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(this, pvhX, pvhY).start();
 name = (CharSequence) event.getLocalState();
            setText(name);
            mDropped = true;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Then I put a bunch of these Buttons and my TextView in my XML-File:

```
 <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:theme="@android:style/DeviceDefault.Light.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">

    <TableRow>

        <com.example.scuba.dragdrop.DropTargetView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="1"

            />

        <com.example.scuba.dragdrop.DropTargetView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"

            />
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="10"
        android:id="@+id/Tv"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="77dp" />
```

and I start the Drag action with a long click on the TextView:

```
public class WriteDigital extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnLongClickListener {
public CharSequence value;
TextView Tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_write_digital);
    Tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tv);
    Tv.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    value = Tv.getText();
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(v);
    v.startDrag(null,shadowBuilder,value,0);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_write_digital, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

So when I start to drag, everything is fine and animating well. But as soon as I drag the TextView onto a Button the app crashes.I get a lot of errors. Some say that the String can not be converted in a spannable??

Also I would like to know if it is better to use Clip Data instead of Local state to pass the text info and how I could to that?
Hope somebody can help.

Here is what my errors look like in logcat:

```
08-21 08:38:15.770  27274-27274/com.example.scuba.arduinoremote E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.scuba.arduinoremote, PID: 27274
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.text.Spannable
            at android.widget.TextView.onDragEvent(TextView.java:8767)
            at android.view.View.dispatchDragEvent(View.java:17401)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1249)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1249)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1249)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1249)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1249)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1249)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1249)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1249)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleDragEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5026)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.access$800(ViewRootImpl.java:96)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3213)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Crash? Please post the logcat error output.

Comment: Please see if my answer helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are using wrong override method of `setText()`

Your code should look like this

```
setText(name, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: So this actually helped! But the app still crashed when I dropped the TextView at first try. So I moved the setText method in the DragEnded case and another setText with empty String in DragStarted. Now all Buttons lose their text when I start to drag but the DropTarget gets the new text, as whished. So I guess I have save the TextProperties of the other Buttons in a field or something and reset them after the Drop. Thank you!

Comment: If you face any different issue feel free to post another question.

Comment: Oh, of course it is even better if I put the setText with empty string in the DragEntered case! Now everything works perfect! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.vijay.dragdrop;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DragController 
{
    private static final String TAG = "DragController";

    /** Indicates the drag is a move. */
    public static int DRAG_ACTION_MOVE = 0;

    /** Indicates the drag is a copy. */
    public static int DRAG_ACTION_COPY = 1;

    private static final int VIBRATE_DURATION = 35;
    private static final boolean PROFILE_DRAWING_DURING_DRAG = false;

    private Context mContext;
    private Vibrator mVibrator;
    private Rect mRectTemp = new Rect();
    private final int[] mCoordinatesTemp = new int[2];

    /** Whether or not we're dragging. */
    private boolean mDragging;

    /** X coordinate of the down event. */
    private float mMotionDownX;

    /** Y coordinate of the down event. */
    private float mMotionDownY;

    /** Info about the screen for clamping. */
    private DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    /** Original view that is being dragged. */
    private View mOriginator;

    /** X offset from the upper-left corner of the cell to where we touched. */
    private float mTouchOffsetX;

    /** Y offset from the upper-left corner of the cell to where we touched. */
    private float mTouchOffsetY;

    /** Where the drag originated */
    private DragSource mDragSource;

    /** The data associated with the object being dragged */
    private Object mDragInfo;

    /** The view that moves around while you drag. */
    private DragView mDragView;

    /** Who can receive drop events */
    private ArrayList<DropTarget> mDropTargets = new ArrayList<DropTarget>();

    private DragListener mListener;

    /** The window token used as the parent for the DragView. */
    private IBinder mWindowToken;

    private View mMoveTarget;
    private DropTarget mLastDropTarget;
    private InputMethodManager mInputMethodManager;

    interface DragListener 
    {
        void onDragStart(DragSource source, Object info, int dragAction);
        void onDragEnd();
    }

    public DragController(Context context) 
    {
        mContext = context;
        mVibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    }

    public void startDrag(View v, DragSource source, Object dragInfo, int dragAction) 
    {
        boolean doDrag = source.allowDrag();
        if (!doDrag)
            return;

        mOriginator = v;
        Bitmap b = getViewBitmap(v);

        if (b == null) 
        {
            return;
        }

        int[] loc = mCoordinatesTemp;
        v.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
        int screenX = loc[0];
        int screenY = loc[1];
        startDrag(b, screenX, screenY, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), source, dragInfo, dragAction);
        b.recycle();

        if (dragAction == DRAG_ACTION_MOVE) 
        {
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public void startDrag(Bitmap b, int screenX, int screenY, int textureLeft, int textureTop, int textureWidth, int textureHeight, DragSource source, Object dragInfo, int dragAction) 
    {
        if (PROFILE_DRAWING_DURING_DRAG) 
        {
            android.os.Debug.startMethodTracing("Launcher");
        }

        if (mInputMethodManager == null) 
        {
            mInputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        }
        mInputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mWindowToken, 0);

        if (mListener != null)
        {
            mListener.onDragStart(source, dragInfo, dragAction);
        }

        int registrationX = ((int) mMotionDownX) - screenX;
        int registrationY = ((int) mMotionDownY) - screenY;
        mTouchOffsetX = mMotionDownX - screenX;
        mTouchOffsetY = mMotionDownY - screenY;
        mDragging = true;
        mDragSource = source;
        mDragInfo = dragInfo;

        mVibrator.vibrate(VIBRATE_DURATION);
        DragView dragView = mDragView = new DragView(mContext, b, registrationX, registrationY, textureLeft, textureTop, textureWidth, textureHeight);
        dragView.show(mWindowToken, (int) mMotionDownX, (int) mMotionDownY);
    }

    private Bitmap getViewBitmap(View v) 
    {
        v.clearFocus();
        v.setPressed(false);

        boolean willNotCache = v.willNotCacheDrawing();
        v.setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);
        int color = v.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();
        v.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(0);

        if (color != 0) 
        {
            v.destroyDrawingCache();
        }
        v.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap cacheBitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
        if (cacheBitmap == null) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed getViewBitmap(" + v + ")", new RuntimeException());
            return null;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cacheBitmap);
        v.destroyDrawingCache();
        v.setWillNotCacheDrawing(willNotCache);
        v.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(color);
        return bitmap;
    }

    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) 
    {
        return mDragging;
    }

    public void cancelDrag() 
    {
        endDrag();
    }

    private void endDrag()
    {
        if (mDragging) 
        {
            mDragging = false;
            if (mOriginator != null) 
            {
                mOriginator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (mListener != null) 
            {
                mListener.onDragEnd();
            }

            if (mDragView != null) 
            {
                mDragView.remove();
                mDragView = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        final int action = ev.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            recordScreenSize();
        }

        final int screenX = clamp((int) ev.getRawX(), 0, mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels);
        final int screenY = clamp((int) ev.getRawY(), 0, mDisplayMetrics.heightPixels);

        switch (action) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mMotionDownX = screenX;
                mMotionDownY = screenY;
                mLastDropTarget = null;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (mDragging) 
                {
                    drop(screenX, screenY);
                }
                endDrag();
                break;
        }
        return mDragging;
    }

    void setMoveTarget(View view)
    {
        mMoveTarget = view;
    }

    public boolean dispatchUnhandledMove(View focused, int direction) 
    {
        return mMoveTarget != null && mMoveTarget.dispatchUnhandledMove(focused, direction);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) 
    {
        if (!mDragging)
        {
            return false;
        }

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        final int screenX = clamp((int) ev.getRawX(), 0, mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels);
        final int screenY = clamp((int) ev.getRawY(), 0, mDisplayMetrics.heightPixels);

        switch (action) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mMotionDownX = screenX;
                mMotionDownY = screenY;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mDragView.move((int) ev.getRawX(), (int) ev.getRawY());
                final int[] coordinates = mCoordinatesTemp;
                DropTarget dropTarget = findDropTarget(screenX, screenY, coordinates);
                if (dropTarget != null) 
                {
                    if (mLastDropTarget == dropTarget) 
                    {
                        dropTarget.onDragOver(mDragSource, coordinates[0], coordinates[1], (int) mTouchOffsetX, (int) mTouchOffsetY, mDragView, mDragInfo);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        if (mLastDropTarget != null) 
                        {
                            mLastDropTarget.onDragExit(mDragSource, coordinates[0], coordinates[1], (int) mTouchOffsetX, (int) mTouchOffsetY, mDragView, mDragInfo);
                        }
                        dropTarget.onDragEnter(mDragSource, coordinates[0], coordinates[1], (int) mTouchOffsetX, (int) mTouchOffsetY, mDragView, mDragInfo);
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    if (mLastDropTarget != null) 
                    {
                        mLastDropTarget.onDragExit(mDragSource, coordinates[0], coordinates[1], (int) mTouchOffsetX, (int) mTouchOffsetY, mDragView, mDragInfo);
                    }
                }
                mLastDropTarget = dropTarget;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (mDragging) 
                {
                    drop(screenX, screenY);
                }
                endDrag();  
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                cancelDrag();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean drop(float x, float y) 
    {
        final int[] coordinates = mCoordinatesTemp;
        DropTarget dropTarget = findDropTarget((int) x, (int) y, coordinates);

        if (dropTarget != null) 
        {
            dropTarget.onDragExit(mDragSource, coordinates[0], coordinates[1], (int) mTouchOffsetX, (int) mTouchOffsetY, mDragView, mDragInfo);
            if (dropTarget.acceptDrop(mDragSource, coordinates[0], coordinates[1], (int) mTouchOffsetX, (int) mTouchOffsetY, mDragView, mDragInfo)) 
            {
                dropTarget.onDrop(mDragSource, coordinates[0], coordinates[1], (int) mTouchOffsetX, (int) mTouchOffsetY, mDragView, mDragInfo);
                mDragSource.onDropCompleted((View) dropTarget, true);
                return true;
            }
            else 
            {
                mDragSource.onDropCompleted((View) dropTarget, false);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private DropTarget findDropTarget(int x, int y, int[] dropCoordinates) 
    {
        final Rect r = mRectTemp;
        final ArrayList<DropTarget> dropTargets = mDropTargets;
        final int count = dropTargets.size();
        for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {
            final DropTarget target = dropTargets.get(i);
            target.getHitRect(r);
            target.getLocationOnScreen(dropCoordinates);
            r.offset(dropCoordinates[0] - target.getLeft(), dropCoordinates[1] - target.getTop());
            if (r.contains(x, y)) 
            {
                dropCoordinates[0] = x - dropCoordinates[0];
                dropCoordinates[1] = y - dropCoordinates[1];
                return target;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void recordScreenSize() 
    {
        ((WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(mDisplayMetrics);
    }

    private static int clamp(int val, int min, int max) 
    {
        if (val < min) 
        {
            return min;
        }
        else if (val >= max) 
        {
            return max - 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            return val;
        }
    }

    public void setWindowToken(IBinder token) 
    {
        mWindowToken = token;
    }

    public void setDragListener(DragListener l) 
    {
        mListener = l;
    }

    public void removeDragListener(DragListener l) 
    {
        mListener = null;
    }

    public void addDropTarget(DropTarget target) 
    {
        mDropTargets.add(target);
    }

    public void removeDropTarget(DropTarget target) 
    {
        mDropTargets.remove(target);
    }
}
```

Comment: So as I said, I am pretty new to Android programming.But I Will go through your code and see what I can get out of it. Thanks!!

Comment: this has a working example of drag and drop and many other usefull android ui tutorials.

Comment: Thanks man! As a beginner I can't get enough good tutorials :)

Comment: Good luck welcome to the world of android.Code for freedom.